# Ubuntu 18.04 sudo apt update error + internet connection problem

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, sudo

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my M1 via a virtual machine called UTM.

The problem is that there is "no wifi adaptor found" in my ubuntu, so I'm trying to run `sudo apt update` , but I get an error saying

```
Err:1 http://kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionicInRelease
  Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://kr .ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http: //ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/InReleas
e  Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease
   Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http: //kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease
   Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-security/InRelease
   Could not resolve 'ports. ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

So I found a solution to a similar problem (error in running apt-get update), which is

1. Run `$ vi /etc/network/interfaces` and add `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`
2. Run `$ vi /etc/resolv.conf` and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` `nameserver 8.8.4.4`
   but I can't type in anything at all ([Screenshot of the terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsD1C.png)).

Can anyone help me with this...?

---

Edit 
I found a way to edit the config files above, but I still can't successfully run `sudo apt update`....

Comment: Are you sure you want to install 18.04? It is not going to be supported in less than 10 months. Why don't you try a newer version like 22.04?

Comment: I'm actually using 20.04, but I suddenly need 18.04 to use ROS Melodic, which is supported in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You need to be `root` (use `sudo`) to edit these files. Please, [edit] your question and add the `ip a` command output.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried running `sudo apt update root` with `root` , but I got the exactly same error code as above. In order to use `ip`, I need to install it with `apt install freeipa-client` , but I get an error code as well, which I think it can be solved by running `apt-get update`. And this again comes back to the original problem.

Comment: At least you can try `ping 1.1.1.1`, `traceroute 8.8.8.8`, `netstat -ni`, `netstat -nr`, etc...

Comment: Umm.. could you please suggest them in detail? I still don't know why I can't type any code in the interfaces file. It's just blocked, and I can't reach under the line `#     sudo apt intstall ifupdown`. (The screenshot I uploaded above)

Comment: Is this helping? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434799/utm-ubuntu-linux-installation-says-network-is-unreachable

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but sadly it's not working for me.. Maybe I should post a new question about this "no wifi adaptor found" problem.